# hadoop namenode -format showing error

Tags: 14.04, hadoop

I am trying to setup Hadoop 3.0.0 on my Ubuntu desktop. I have done all the required setups, but when running the command `./hadoop namenode -format` to format name it shows error:

```
root@DESKTOP-JIUFBOR:/usr/local/hadoop/hadoop-3.0.0/bin# ./hadoop namenode -format
WARNING: Use of this script to execute namenode is deprecated.
WARNING: Attempting to execute replacement "hdfs namenode" instead.

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/apache/hadoop/hdfs/server/namenode/NameNode : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:482)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the 3.x version, Apache Hadoop requires using Java 8 or newer. You need just to update Java and try again.

Comment: Thanks @Alex Chermenin. Updating jdk from 1.7 to 1.8 solved the issue.

Comment: @AmitSingla You're welcome. If all right, could you mark the answer as "accepted"?